# Container-Optimized OS - Erro Log everyhour

Tags: google-compute-engine, operating-system

I have one VM with ContainerOS with the specific configuration:

```
Image: cos-stable-76-12239-60-0
Machine: g1-small (1 vCPUj, 1,7 GB)
CPU: Intel Broadwell
```

Every hour this VM log these erros message:

```
Failed to call method: org.chromium.SessionManagerInterface.RetrieveActiveSessions: object_path= /org/chromium/SessionManager: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.chromium.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files
```

```
CallMethodAndBlockWithTimeout(...): Domain=dbus, Code=org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown, Message=The name org.chromium.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files
```

```
Error calling D-Bus proxy call to interface '/org/chromium/SessionManager': The name org.chromium.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files
```

Theses erros are from this CMD line `/sbin/crash_sender --max_spread_time=0`, i do not know what to do to solve this erro, it is something related to O.S.

Someone have a solution?

Comment: What is running /sbin/crash_sender? Also, what is the VM itself used for?

Answer (score 1):

The crash collection software in COS was originally built for Chromebooks (the laptop using Chrome browser). So the code typically expects Chrome and some other related software on the system.
However, COS is a server OS, and does not have Chrome. So if Chrome is missing, the software will report some errors.

They are actually not real failures, just some verbose error messages so it’s safe to ignore these logs.

So far there’s no known way to remove them from what I’ve researched. There’s currently tests being run to resolve this issue.